# Gap between list-items with floated elements in IE7 (with isolated test case)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having huge difficulties in removing the gap between list items in **IE7**.

The problem with gap between the list-items occurs when I am floating elements inside the li:s.

A simple test case is here (with 2 different possible solutions that didn't work):
http://jsfiddle.net/UJMr8/1/

...And here is the HTML from the test:

```
<ul>
    <li class="even">
        <span class="left">left</span>
        <span class="right">right</span>
    </li>
    <li class="odd">
        <span class="left">left</span>
        <span class="right">right</span>
    </li>
    <li class="even">
        <span class="left">left</span>
        <span class="right">right</span>
    </li>
    <li class="odd">
        <span class="left">left</span>
        <span class="right">right</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With the following css:

```
li     { height: 30px; line-height: 30px; padding: 0 10px; }
.even  { background: #ccc; }
.odd   { background: #eee; }
.left  { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
```

Any suggestions or thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you pls. add a printscreen? I think the padding is the problem (guess is dubled in IE). But i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Thanks for the comment, I hadn't test it in other browsers. So, you can use conditional comments, to target internet explorer only like this

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
 li {height:0px;}
<![endif]-->
```

Or you can use an external css, to target internet explorer 7 for any other problem you may have and you can't find a cross browser solution:

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Another option is to use an internet explorer hack, like asterisk `*`. An example is

```
*height:0px;
```

The hack must be below the `height:30px` to be able to override it.

I suggest you to use conditional comments, instead the hack.

Comment: Nice, it works in IE7, but fails in other browsers ( safari/firefox ). I am looking for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: I like to use this technique insted: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: @Fred looks interesting, but a little bit messy I think. But use whatever you feel comfortable :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Eric Meyers CSS Reset?

http://www.cssreset.com/downloads/css-resets/eric-meyer-reset-css/eric-meyer-reset.css

It sets all browser default margin and padding to 0

Comment: It's not about reset. If you check the fiddle you can see it's included at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a lot of problems with styling list items if you don't change their display to block and reset them properly.

Add this to the top of your css:

```
ul li, ul {
  list-style:None;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: it's a generic reset. I wanted to isolate which parts were applicable to list item